# How to see if I connected to an ephemeral port?

Tags: linux, networking

I'm working on a port scanner that uses Linux [`connect`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) system call and when I'm scanning localhost, sometimes I get false positives due to kernel allocating me the source port for the connection that is equal to the destination port. Is there a way to tell if the connection I established was made to an ephemeral port?

Comment: Does this happen specifically when you are using datagram sockets?

Comment: This happens when I'm making a TCP connection. I also noticed that it doesn't affect 3.14.2 kernel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`getsockname`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockname.2.html) to find out the local port the kernel assigned. Alternatively, you could use [`bind`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) to pick the port yourself.